# CABasicAnimation animate (seek) to a position in time over an entire timeline

Tags: ios

I'm wondering if the following is possible with CoreAnimation.

Like the title says, I'd like to animate or seek if you will, to a position in time over an entire timeline animation.

For example, say I create a CABasicAnimation which animates a CALayer's color from blue to red over an entire timeline of 10 seconds with an easing function of EaseOut.

Rather than playing that animation from start to finish, I'd prefer finer control.

For example, I'd like to say animateTo(50%) of the entire animation.  This would result in an animation starting at 0% and animating to 50% of the entire animation with an ease out function.  So the animation would last 5 seconds and we'd be in the middle of our color transform.

After this I could say, animateTo(20%).  This would result in an animation starting from our current position of 50% and animating in reverse to 20% of the total animation. So we'd end up with a 3 second animation and we'd be 20% into our color transform from blue to red.

In the end we're just animating to a position in time over the entire timeline.  I could easily say animateTo(5 seconds) rather than animateTo(50%).  Or animateTo(2 seconds) rather than animateTo(20%).

I've been reading up on CoreAnimation and it appears I am un-able to get this kind of control.  Has anyone else tried this with CoreAnimation?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no "built-in" way to do this using core animation. You could create a method that would do what you want, but in it, you would be calling a new animation method each time that would start from the current value and go to the new value. This would require that you can calculate what 50% of the way from blue to red means (or whatever values you're animating between).

Comment: Hey rdelmar thanks for the quick response!  I was afraid of that.  I will be doing linear translations so it won't be too difficult to compute those new values.

Answer (score 1):

The latest SDK adds a bit to UIKit animation. 
It might suit your needs...

According to the documentation:

> New object-based, fully interactive and interruptible animation support that lets you retain control of your animations and link them with gesture-based interactions

The new shiny `UIViewPropertyAnimator`:

```
let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 3.0, curve: .easeInOut) {
    self.myView.alpha = 0
}
animator.startAnimation()

animator.pauseAnimation()
animator.isReversed = true
animator.fractionComplete = 1.5 / CGFloat(animator.duration)
```

However there are some limitations: 
The PropertyAnimator requires targeting **iOS 10** (which is still in beta as at the time of writing).
Also the animations are limited to UIView **Animatable Properties**, which are:

- `frame`
- `bounds`
- `center`
- `transform`
- `alpha`
- `backgroundColor`
- `contentStretch`

If you seek more flexibility and features take a look at some open source libraries like [TRX](https://github.com/Trxy/TRX) and [Advance](https://github.com/storehouse/Advance):

```
import TRX

let tween = Tween(from: 0, to: 1, time:3, ease:Ease.Quad.easeOut) {
    anyObject.anyProperty = $0
}
let reversed = tween.reversed()
reversed.seek(1.5)
reversed.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, there is no built-in function. But if you want to create your own solution, here are a few notes and useful functions that are already there.

The `CABasicAnimation` conforms to the `CAMediaTiming´ protocol and contains some neat functionality for your use case:

- `timeOffset` - this value determines at what time into the animation you actually want to start, if you have a animation with a duration of 2 seconds and timeOffset set to 1, it will cause the animation to start in the middle.
- `speed` - setting that value to -1 would cause the animation to reverse (e.g. for the case of from 50% to 20%)
- `duration` - might be changed if you want to change the duration of the animation for shorter changes e.g. form 40% to 50%.
- `timingFunction` - I was hoping it might be possible to provide a custom timing function here, which for example just completes the animation after 1 second even if the duration is set to be 5 seconds, meaning: a linear function between 0 and 1 and after that just constant. It may however be possible to achieve an approximation of that with a bezierPath as well.